# How to protect app against read access violation while accessing to pointer's value?

Tags: c++

I've created some chain-like structure, where one object has pointers to the next and previous object of a chain. The code below loops through entire chain, looks for value specified in arguments and removes matching element (if exists).

```
void List::removeElementByValue(int value)
{
    ListMember* nextElem = this->firstValue;
    while (nextElem) {
        if (nextElem == NULL || nextElem == nullptr) {
            break;
        }

        if (nextElem->value == value) {
            if (nextElem->prevValue)
                (nextElem->prevValue)->nextValue = nextElem->nextValue;
            if (nextElem->nextValue)
                (nextElem->nextValue)->prevValue = nextElem->prevValue;
            delete nextElem;
            this->count--;
            return;
        }
        nextElem = nextElem->prevValue;
    }
}
```

The problem is: I'm getting this error when I'm trying to remove non-existent value from chain.

> Exception thrown: read access violation. nextElem was 0xCDCDCDCD.

Function should do nothing in that case. It happens at this line:

```
 if (nextElem->value == value) {
```

As you see, I've used multiple ways to check if nextElem is correct, but I'm still getting this error. Any ways I can prevent that?

Comment: You most likely have an uninitialized pointer - reading its value is *undefined behavior*, you can't "guard" against that. You need to make sure it is initialized

Comment: The best protection in C++ is to use modern alternative to raw pointers like `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, or `weak_ptr`. The language itself doesn't give you any protection against invalid memory access, but good style and convention can.

Comment: *I've created some chain-like structure* -- In other words a doubly-linked list, and in other words again [std::list<int>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).  Consider using that instead.

Comment: Marginally related:  Wikipedia has a good list of [common debugging magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values) and their meanings. When you get a number like 0xCDCDCDCD, check the list to see if the program's trying to tell you something.

Answer (score 1):

> `if (nextElem == NULL || nextElem == nullptr)`

This will always be false when `while (nextElem)` is true.

> `nextElem = nextElem->prevValue;`

This needs to use `nextValue` instead of `prevValue`.

But, most importantly, you are not updating `this->firstValue` if the `value` is found in the first element of the list, so you end up deleting the `firstValue` and leave it pointing at invalid memory.

Try this instead:

```
void List::removeElementByValue(int value)
{
    ListMember* elem = this->firstValue;
    while (elem) {
        if (elem->value == value) {
            if (elem->prevValue)
                elem->prevValue->nextValue = elem->nextValue;
            if (elem->nextValue)
                elem->nextValue->prevValue = elem->prevValue;

            // ADD THIS!!!
            if (elem == this->firstValue)
                this->firstValue = elem->nextValue;

            delete elem;
            this->count--;
            return;
        }

        elem = elem->nextValue;  // NOT prevValue!
    }
}
```

A better solution is to not implement a linked list manually in the first place. Use the standard [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container instead, let it do all of the hard hard for you.

```
#include <list>

class List
{
private:
    std::list<int> values;
    ...
};

...

#include <algorithm>

void List::removeElementByValue(int value)
{
    auto iter = std::find(values.begin(), values.end(), value);
    if (iter != values.end())
        values.erase(iter);
}
```